# How to check that the variable is empty or not

Tags: laravel

This is my ProfileController:

```
 public function index()
   {
   $id = Auth::user()->id;
   $address = DB::table('addresses')->where('user_id', '=', $id)->get();
   return view('/Pages.profile',['address'=>$address]);
   }
```

I want this address from database to be printed on view, if the address is empty than a link to add address is shown..if it's not empty than display the address for particular users.
This is profile view:

```
@if(!empty($address))
@foreach($address as $row)
    <p><strong>Address : </strong>{{ $row->house_no }}, {{ $row->location }}, {{ $row->landmark }}</p>
    <p><strong> City : </strong>{{ $row->city }}</p>
    <p><strong>State : </strong> {{ $row->state }}</p>
    <p><strong>Pin Code : </strong>{{ $row->pin_code}}</p>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod1">Edit address</a> 
@endforeach
```

@else
       Add address
@endif

Add address link does not show up even if the $address is empty. Any suggestions where I made the mistake

Comment: look up forelse blade construct. It's exactly what you are looking for. https://www.neontsunami.com/posts/laravels-new-forelse-construct

Comment: thanks I used count to and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `isNotEmpty` method.

> From [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-isnotempty)
>
> > The isNotEmpty method returns true if the collection is not empty; otherwise, false is returned

so it should be like this:

```
@if($address->isNotEmpty())

@else
  Add address
@endof
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel [eloquent get() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models) will return you a collection

Use `count()` method to check if it doesn't have any elements like:

```
@if($address->count() !== 0)

@else
    add address
@endif
```

Or

```
@if(!$address->isEmpty())
```